# Intelligent Searching with wildcards (*) and word grouping in SQL Full-text Search

Tags: sql, algorithm, search, syntax, full-text-search

What's the best way implement MS SQL full-text search using all the normal things like wildcards and quotations.  For example:

If the search term the user inputs is

> Overdose of "Vitamin C" for child*

I would like to treat "Vitamin C" as one phrase and would like to match "child" and "children"

The documentation offers so many alternatives, it's hard to differentiate them.  I'd love to be able to throw the above string at Full-text search and have it decipher the word grouping and the wildcards, but I don't think it's that smart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a very nice article [Normalizing SQL Server Full-text Search Conditions](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/05/normalizing_sql.html).

It saved a bunch of time for me.